# Как сравнить скрипты

Tags: javascript, поиск-программ, минификация

Есть два скрипта. Один минифицированный, а другой - нет. Минифицированный является более ранней версией полного.

Хочу увидеть разницу в коде - такую же, как я бы получил при сравнении WinMerge или любой утилитой системы контроля версий, если бы файл не был минифицирован.

Существует ли какая-либо программа, которая выполнит сравнение двух версий кода без учёта имён переменных и последствий минификации (типа убирания точек с запятой)?

Comment: Существуют ли `sourcemaps` от минификации?

Comment: Минификатор известен хоть? У меня была недавно такая задача, я так ничего пристойного не нашел, отчаялся и ручками с матами "разминифицировал" старый при помощи http://jsbeautifier.org/ (там еще пара полезных ссылок есть кстати) и инструментов ide. Но в моем случае было неизвестно чем именно жали.

Comment: Думаю нужно пролоббировать галку "Мелкая правка", не выводящую пост в ленту

Comment: @vp_arth, нет. Но в тот раз помогла повторная минификация обоих онлайн-минификатором, после которой код скармливается в beautifier, а потом в win-merge. Но это сработает только в случае отсутствия значительных изменений.

Comment: @vp_arth, если соурсмепы есть то неинтересно)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, нет, минификатор неизвестен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда подозреваю что жизнь-боль) Но если нет, то лично мне ответ тоже был бы очень полезен)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, ответ из комментария выше не годится в твоём случае?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, там были значительные изменения =). Ну и в любом случае конкретно с этой задачей я уже успешно довозился и больше не придется, мне на будущее любопытно

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, как и мне :)

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная задача, попробовал https://prettydiff.com, смог найти нужные дифы, не уверен как это работает с глобальными изменениями.

Пробовал в браузере, минутку пришлось подождать, так что если что то совсем большое, то можно клиент для терминала попробовать, на [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettydiff) есть мини документация.

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, работает ли оно...

Comment: Что конкретно? Браузер подвис?

Comment: Хм.. Дизайн сомнительный - я кнопку не заметил... Всё равно работает не так как требуется. Там обычное текстовое сравнение: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWJ6v.png

Comment: Да, вижу. У меня была задача на сравнение двух билдов после `create-reacta-app` то было удобно, я не думал что он постоянно одни и те же переменные называет одинаково, поэтому предположил что это парсер так сделал. Тогда у меня нет вариантов